# Get text after certain point using NSString

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring

I am getting a url of a file when a user opens one from an NSOpenPanel for example like so:

```
/Users/Name/Documents/MyFile.png
```

So I just want this bit:

```
MyFile.png
```

However the user could have a file name of any length so how can I say, only get the string after the last forward slash (/)? I just want to get the file name.

Comment: Search the string backwards for a forward slash, and take the substring from there onwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSString *fileName = [someStringContainingAPath **lastPathComponent**];

More general advice: spend a little time reading through the reference pages for NSString and NSString(UIStringDrawing). There are a lot of useful methods in there that you might not otherwise know to look for. In addition to -lastPathComponent demonstrated above, there's -pathComponents, -componentsSeparatedByString:, and many other handy tools.

Comment: Small issue. When I send this to the console shows up great, only I can't seem to actually get the string value from it. It seems to stay formatted as it came.

Comment: Fixed, just needed to retain it.